# How send data from webservice? objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am using webservice. 
Below is link for web service for storing your data.

http://www.chandrakumar.com/iphone_soap_server.php

WSDL URL : http://www.chandrakumar.com/iphone_soap_server.php?wsdl

4 parameters  are required for calling insertdata method in this service :
1. name
2. phone
3. email
4. score
on successful  insertion you will get message "user information has been saved"

for this event i use this code.

```
 -(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{

NSString *name = txt_name.text;
NSString *phone = txt_phone.text;
NSString *email = txt_email.text;
NSString *score = txt_score.text;
NSString *urlpath;
urlpath = [@"http://www.chandrakumar.com/" stringByAppendingString:@"iphone_soap_server.php?name="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:name];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:@"&phone="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:phone];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:@"&email="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:email];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:@"&score="];
urlpath = [urlpath stringByAppendingString:score];

NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlpath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *a = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setTimeoutInterval:60];
//NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMsg length]];
//  [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//  [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//  [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//  [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];

NSData *responseData= [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

//RMAppDelegate *apDelObj = (RMAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if(error.domain != nil)
{
    NSString *errorDesc=[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
    //apDelObj.globalError = errorDesc;
    NSLog(@"%@",errorDesc);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"nil error");
}

NSLog( @"%@",responseData);
}
```

But i am not getting response message "user information has been saved". What is erorr in this method?  I wan to store four parameters in server. How do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check here..

```
if(error.domain != nil)
{
    NSString *errorDesc=[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
    //apDelObj.globalError = errorDesc;
    NSLog(@"%@",errorDesc);
}
else {
    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"Result : %@", str);
}
```